# Where can I get Insurance claim data for practicing NLP(Natural Language) processing?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science-model, nlp

I am looking for specifically Insurance dataset for practicing Machine Learning & NLP, but unable to find much in kaggle, udemy or other websites. Is there a way to get that dataset or any website that stores this.

I am mainly looking for NLP practice for automatic claim generation or other insurance activities, please suggest the approach

Answer (score 2):

I am working in the same industry for a few years now and I can tell you that there are no publicly available datasets because of the nature of the documents. They are quite private and contains sensitive information, that are bound by rules and regulations.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but if I have to practice and prove my NLP skills in insurance, how do I proceed?

Comment: It depends on what you want to solve with NLP. There are open source datasets for different NLP tasks, what in the insurance industry do you want to solve with regards to claim data?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is unavailability of dataset in case of NLP one of the approach I have followed is to generate dataset using templates based approach. The implementation looks like this

```
cities = ['paris', 'munich', 'new york']
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'sunday', 'friday']

templates = ['i am flying from {cities} to {cities}',
'my flight is arriving in {cities} on next {days}']
```

So now write a script that helps you to fill these missing values present inside templates.